# on macports, what ports are supported by 'port select'?

Tags: rvm, macports

I know 'port select' works with gcc and python --> is there a way to get a full list of all the ports that are switchable by 'port select'?

(I want to make a generic 'select' util that delegates to rvm, port select, etc. and quickly let's me switch entire toolset chains)

thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way to ask the port select tool itself for a list, but just check the directory `/opt/local/etc/select`. Each selectable group has a directory there.

Answer (score 7):

Raim's answer works with ports that have been previously installed. For a more comprehensive list, try:

```
port echo '*_select' | cut -d_ -f1
```